# Loop implementation to XML file in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm making an app in AndroidStudio that is generating 20 random pictures, I manage to make it work but my xml file that generate them is looking like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="cardImages">
        <item>https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=1</item>
        <item>https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=2</item>
        <item>https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=3</item>
        <item>https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=4</item>
        <item>https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=5</item>
        <item>https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=6</item>
        <item>https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=7</item>
        <item>https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=8</item>
        <item>https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=9</item>
        <item>https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=10</item>
        <item>https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=11</item>
        <item>https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=12</item>
        <item>https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=13</item>
        <item>https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=14</item>
        <item>https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=15</item>
        <item>https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=16</item>
        <item>https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=17</item>
        <item>https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=18</item>
        <item>https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=19</item>
        <item>https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=20</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

What I want to know is if there is any way that I can transform this into a for loop in my `MainActivity.kt` that increments that last number on the URL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
val url = "https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=${Random.nextInt(1, 21)}"
```

or

```
// you could store this anywhere, if you want to keep URLs organised
const val BASE_URL = "https://picsum.photos/200/300?random="

// a function like this could handle different URLs if you like,
// or min/max values for the random number
fun getRandomImageUrl() = BASE_URL + Random.nextInt(1, 21)
```

There's no real benefit from having the URL as a string resource, unless you needed to access it from XML too for some reason. It's not something that needs to be translated either. But if you *did* want to store it in there, you could just store a template string:

```
// add an argument - in this case a decimal number
<string name="cardImageUrl">https://picsum.photos/200/300\?random=%1$d</string>

// then in your code (where you can call getString on a Context)
val url = getString(R.string.cardImageUrl, Random.nextInt(1, 21))
```

([Don't forget to escape the `?`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#escaping_quotes))

---

If you really do want to generate all of them instead of random ones:

```
val urls = (1..20).map { num -> "https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=$num" }
```